# Using NSBatchInsertRequest to insert data into coredata

Tags: swift, nsbatchupdaterequest, nsbatchdeleterequest

Inserting data into coredata I'm using **NSBatchInsertRequest**, but my data is properly inserted. However, is erasing data from coredata possible while using **NSBatchDeleteRequest**? My data is not saving. When I am fetching the data I my getting nil value.

**code for insert data to coredata**

```
    func create<T: NSManagedObject>(type: T.Type, object: [[String: Any]]) throws {
    
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
       
          let batchInsert = NSBatchInsertRequest(entityName: "\(type)", objects: object)
        
      try managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.execute(batchInsert, with: managedObjectContext)
        
        do {
            try saveIfNeeded()} catch {
            
        }
        
         }
```

**managedobject is**

```
 lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        guard let modelURL = Bundle(for: EmployeeDataStore.self).url(forResource: "JsonEmployeeDataStore", withExtension: "momd")
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to find XCDataModeld File")
        }
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed initializing the momd file: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let coord = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = coord

        guard let documentURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
        else {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to find document url.")
        }
        // Odd issue where simulator doesn't have documents folder
        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentURL.absoluteString) {
            try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: documentURL,
                                                     withIntermediateDirectories: true,
                                                     attributes: nil)
        }

        let storeURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("JsonEmployeeDataStore.sqlite")

        do {
            let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
                           NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
            try coord.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType,
                                         configurationName: nil,
                                         at: storeURL,
                                         options: options)
        } catch {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to get database.")
        }

        return moc
    }()
```

```
struct DataAccess<T: NSManagedObject> {

    func create(object: [[String: Any]]) throws{
          try DataStore.shared.create(type: T.self, object: object)
      }

    func getAll(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws -> [T] {
        try DataStore.shared.getAll(predicate: predicate)
    }

    func removeAll(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) throws {
        try DataStore.shared.removeAll(type: T.self, predicate: predicate)
    }

    func save() throws {
        try DataStore.shared.saveIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

```
  public func update(key: String, data: Data, userid: String, expires: Date? = nil) throws {

           try removeStoreValues(key: key, userid: userid)

           let object = [
           [
               "key": Int64(storePersistentHash(value: key)),
               "data": data,
               "userId": userid,
               "created": Date(),
               "expires": expires

           ]
           ]

           try dataAccess.create(object: object)

          try dataAccess.save()
       }
```

```
  func saveIfNeeded() throws {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
    }
}
```

Data should be inserted to database properly.

Comment: What is your question? Your title is about inserting, which you then say is fine, but then you talk about deleting, but you don't actually say what the problem is

Comment: My data is not saving. When I am fetching the data I my getting nil value.

Comment: What is `saveIfNeeded`? And why do you ignore the caught error in `create`?

Comment: I have added my "saveIfNeeded" function. And removed the delete function

Comment: Sorry your code is confusing. Basically it's not needed to save the context after calling `execute(batchInsert`. And in `update` you call `save` twice, once in `create` and then a second time directly. Why do you use this antique method to create the store? There is `NSPersistentContainer` for a very long time. And `fileExists(atPath: documentURL.absoluteString` evaluates **always** to false because it's the wrong API. And what is `removeStoreValues`? And it's much less effort to update **one** record with read-modify-write rather than via batch insert.